# How should I pass data between small functions - via closures or via properties of an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, design-patterns, functional-programming

I have a complex buisness action for example deleting a user account. It contains multiple connected steps, and has to keep track of some state between steps. What is a better approach for writing this `action`?

I see a lot of more `functional` approach like one below.

```
function someAction(someParam, anotherParam, callback) {

    async.waterfall([
            step1,
            step2,
            step3,
            step4
            ],callback
    );

    function step1(p,cb){/**use someParam and anotherParam here via closure*/}
    function step2(p,cb){/**...*/}
    function step3(p,cb){/**...*/}
    function step4(p,cb){/**...*/}
};

someAction('value', 1241, (err)=>{/**...*/});
```

What I don't like about this approach is that everything is defined within the scope of a single function (here `someAction`).

I find a more `object-oriented` way to be a little more readable. The state and the `stepX` functions are not truly private - sometimes it is convenient for testing.

```
function SomeAction(someParam, anotherParam){
    //private state
    this._someParam = someParam;
    this._anotherParam = anotherParam;
};

SomeAction.prototype._step1 = function(p, cb){
    //use this._someParam and this._anotherParam
};

SomeAction.prototype._step2 = function(p, cb){
    //use this._someParam and this._anotherParam
};

SomeAction.prototype._step3 = function(p, cb){
    //use this._someParam and this._anotherParam
};

SomeAction.prototype._step4 = function(p, cb){
    //use this._someParam and this._anotherParam
};

//public api
SomeAction.prototype.execute = function(callback) {
    async.waterfall([
                this._step1,
                this._step2,
                this._step3,
                this._step4
            ],callback
    )
};

new SomeAction('value', 1241).execute((err)=>{/**...*/})
```

Is there any performance difference between them ? What is the recommended approach in Node.js ? Is it true that each time I call`someAction` in functional approach - all the `stepX` functions have to be defined from scratch ?

Comment: The recommended approach is the one that is more readable to you and that matches your requirements (testability). The performance difference would be negligible.

Comment: The best solution would be to use promises. Which are both objects and functional.

Comment: **Functional doesn't mean to put the entire logic into a single function**. It means to design small functions each with a single purpose and then to compose those functions to form more complex ones. With the functional paradigm you don't obtain encapsulation but code reuse and improved maintainability by the lack of side effects.

Comment: @LUH3417 Thanks for the explanation! Both approaches I presented are composed of many small functions (I love this style - recommended by Uncle Bob). The question is how should I pass data between those small functions - via closures or via properties of an object. Uncle bob suggests that class is a bag for data and methods that manipulate it.

Comment: Now I got it. I was confused because you defined the `stepX` functions inside the wrapper (to close over them of course) and thus can't reuse them anymore. You can pass the changing state around as an additional argument and abstract it away by using a state monad. If the shared state isn't changing, the reader monad is an alternative. Another question is whether you work with immutable data. Ultimately I think the question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

You could create curried versions of your step functions and stick them into the waterfall.

```
function step1(arg1, arg2, cb){
  // Fuction body...
}

// other steps would be defined here...

function step4(arg1, cb){
  // fuction body...
}

curried_step1 = step1.bind(undefined, 'junk', 'garb');
// Other steps curried here...
curried_step4 = step4.bind(undefined, 'something');

async.waterfall([
            curried_step1,
            curried_step2,
            curried_step3,
            curried_step4
        ],callback
);
```

Another approach could be to wrap up your data and state into an object (in place of a real monad) and use that object to pass around what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Promises, for a style that looks like so:

```
var Promise = require('promise');

//** Execute Program **//
main();

/**
 * Do your async logic flow here
 */
function main() {
  step1()
    .then(step2) //Wait for step1 to finish, and pass the response directly to step2
    .then(function(res) {
      // Do something with res (the return from step2)
      // Async execute step3 & step4
      var promises = [
        step3(),
        step4()
      ];

      // Wait for step3 & step4 to finish:
      Promise.all([promises[0], promises[1]]).then(function(values) {
        console.log(values[0]); //Value from step3
        console.log(values[1]); //Value from step4
      }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log(e); //Reject or thrown errors from steps3 or 4
      });
    }).catch(function(e) {
      console.log(e); //Reject or thrown errors from steps1 or 2
    });
}

function step1() {
  return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
    //some async task here
    resolve('step1'); 
    //reject('step1'); //Or trigger a .catch (i.e. this function failed)
  });
}

function step2() {
  return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
    //some async task here
    resolve('step2'); 
    //reject('step2'); //Or trigger a .catch (i.e. this function failed)
  });
}

function step3() {
  return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
    //some async task here
    resolve('step3'); 
    //reject('step3'); //Or trigger a .catch (i.e. this function failed)
  });
}

function step4() {
  return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
    //some async task here
    resolve('step4'); 
    //reject('step4'); //Or trigger a .catch (i.e. this function failed)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite an answer but answers your indirect question:

> The question is how should I pass data between those small functions - via closures or via properties of an object.

There's a third way. If you are familiar with OO design then you might be familiar with the concept of the **command pattern**. That is, you need to construct a function dynamically but that's not possible so you create an object with one method that you can then customise based on the object's properties.

In functional programming, this design pattern is equivalent to the **function factory** pattern. Basically you write a function to generate another function.

So, you want to pass `someParam` and `anotherParam` to the async function but you want to be able to write that function outside of the `someAction` function. Here's how you can do it:

```
function someAction (someParam, anotherParam, callback) {

    async.waterfall([
        make_step1(someParam,anotherParam),
        make_step2(someParam,anotherParam)
        /* ... */
        ],callback
    );
}

function make_step1 (someParam, anotherParam) {
    return function (p, cb) {
        // use someParam and anotherParam here
    }
}

function make_step2 (someParam, anotherParam) {
    return function (p, cb) {
        // use someParam and anotherParam here
    }
}

// ...
```

This removes the main objection you raised with the functional code: you no longer have to define all step functions inside `someAction()`, which makes it look more similar to the OO code.

This still does create new instances of all the step functions (only now returned from the make functions) every time you call `someAction()`. But the interpreter won't have to compile the functions again. Instead only a new closure is created (think of a closure as a frozen stack frame that is unlinked from the program stack).

Comment: V8 uses JIT - do you know `function factory` affects performance?

Comment: @JanOsch: The only way to test is to benchmark. The function returned is actually compiled just once. So it will have the same compilation performance as objects. In theory both objects and closures are malloc'ed at runtime so they should have identical speed performance in memory allocation/de-allocation. Closures do have a slightly more complicated stack management to perform when called but then again objects have a slightly more complicated memory allocation when created (checking inheritance etc.). So the only way to know which is better for your use-case is to benchmark